# CORS error when using Google Elevation API

Tags: google-maps-api, ajax

I'm trying to use Google elevation API with an AJAX request. It doesn't work and when I do console.log(ajax.responseText) I'm getting this error :

Cross-Origin Request Blocking: The Same Origin policy does not allow you to view the remote resource located at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536 , -104.9847034 & key = AIzaSyBXSbBWMZtGL2whXVC7T8wFhQcwcKGRuF4. Reason: The CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is missing.

Does someone knows how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CORS proxy such as [CORS-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere). A hosted CORS proxy can be found [here (herokuapp.com)](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/). Usage is as follows (append location etc. yourself):

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json
```

Answer (score 0):

A comment to [this similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31404834/9778755) points to the [Elevation API's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/start), which suggests to use the [Maps JS API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation) for client-side requests. It has a handy `getElevationForLocations()` method that should not throw a CORS error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cross domains open the web.config locate `<httpProtocol>` and add:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS" />      
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```